# Symfony form routing

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to set the action for a form, so that after the form is submitted it is sent to the controller I designate to handle it.

```
{{form_start(form, {'action' : path('BlogBundle:Comment:create')})}}

    {{ form_widget(form) }}

{{form_end(form)}}
```

The method that I want to call is located in

```
BlogBundle
   -Controller
     -CommentController
       -createAction()
```

I am getting exception

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route
>   "BlogBundle:Comment:create" as such route does not exist.") in
>   BlogBundle:Default:form.html.twig at line 1.

My question is how do I set the path to the method that I want? And also, as a side question, how can I handle submitted forms?

Comment: Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html to see how to name a route then here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html for processing forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BlogBundle:Comment:create` is a controller name, not a route name. Either give your route a name (i.e. `@Route(name="create_comment")` and use that name to create the route:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action' : path('create_comment')}) }}
```

Comment: This actually works, I tought that I can access method like this `Bundle:Controller:method`, I guess I can't